# Gitlab docker runner does not run pipeline jobs

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a gitlab runner that is running on my local machine. I disabled all the other shared runners in my repository, and configured my runner exactly according to the [runner/install/docker tutorial](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html).

When I select `shell` as the executor, the pipeline runs fine. However, when I select `docker` as the executor as they specify in the tutorial, I get the following message on gitlab:

`This job is stuck because the project doesn't have any runners online assigned to it.Go to project CI settings`

My docker runner is enabled and configured exactly like the shell runner that is working with no problem, I only followed the steps outlined in the abovementioned docker tutorial.
On gitlab, my runner is enabled under the "Active runners" section:

[image]

[image]

This is the result of `docker inspect <image hash>`:

```
% docker  inspect 145a3d0b000e700e0ee87ad7d0ed26f2c5e2f10a7334f94802b6cd60bdabcd16
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:145a3d0b000e700e0ee87ad7d0ed26f2c5e2f10a7334f94802b6cd60bdabcd16",
        "RepoTags": [
            "gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [
            "gitlab/gitlab-runner@sha256:207a72393d0f5da5078e5c61039e495aa5727c5bf9a7d4bea0cde72ce9ae26fe"
        ],
        "Parent": "",
        "Comment": "buildkit.dockerfile.v0",
        "Created": "2023-02-02T16:27:53.208812304Z",
        "Container": "",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": null,
            "Cmd": null,
            "Image": "",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": null
        },
        "DockerVersion": "",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "run",
                "--user=gitlab-runner",
                "--working-directory=/home/gitlab-runner"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "",
            "Volumes": {
                "/etc/gitlab-runner": {},
                "/home/gitlab-runner": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/usr/bin/dumb-init",
                "/entrypoint"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "org.opencontainers.image.ref.name": "ubuntu",
                "org.opencontainers.image.version": "20.04"
            },
            "StopSignal": "SIGQUIT"
        },
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 706603328,
        "VirtualSize": 706603328,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/442844f68437704d9950f9613eda83e9b1b2e7ca159682f9d981a45207f74c24/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/44ed4b6ca8fa1ee991f93e551c8aa57598ddd510f934e96ed5f6417221835592/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/263e1ed7165ebfe9a7b158a8ddc96ce6f3c8d51dbfb1bd1063b8ed02e0f03ec4/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/263e1ed7165ebfe9a7b158a8ddc96ce6f3c8d51dbfb1bd1063b8ed02e0f03ec4/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/263e1ed7165ebfe9a7b158a8ddc96ce6f3c8d51dbfb1bd1063b8ed02e0f03ec4/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:d543b8cad89e3428ac8852a13cb2dbfaf55b1e10fd95a9753e51faf393d60e81",
                "sha256:ec62d73d1c4bd3feb4b9d3630f9728c127076c4f63d2de15534cd6a524d5c3ee",
                "sha256:e156984aefdb9217aa8df6efaa022838b0a2706bba77ff12855c2f2c2e8a58a0"
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "LastTagTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        }
    }
]
```

What am I missing in my configuration that is preventing me from running my pipeline in my container?

Comment: I read the sentence "When I select shell as the executor, the pipeline runs fine. However, when I select shell as the executor as they specify in the tutorial, I get the following message on gitlab" multiple times and I don't see the difference between "shell" and "shell".

I can only guess that the registration of the runner is wrong or you are using a wrong "tag" in the pipeline which doesn't match your runner.

Comment: @MichaelDreher sorry for this typo, I meant to say that the `docker` executor does not work, whereas the `shell` executor does with the exact same settings. I edited the question accordingly

Comment: so did you register a runner with docker executor? `What am I missing in my configuration` Please _show_ your configuration. `My docker runner is enabled` How are you checking that?  `and configured exactly like the shell runner` Please show the configuration.  `the project doesn't have any runners` Is the runner enabled for the project?

Comment: @KamilCuk I added more info on my current setup. For my configuration, I literally only followed the steps outlined in the gitlab runner docker install tutorial: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html#general-gitlab-runner-docker-image-usage

Comment: So you are running a gitlab-runner docker container? `"Volumes": {
                "/etc/gitlab-runner": {},
                "/home/gitlab-runner": {}
            },` ther eis no /var/run/docker.sock. See https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html#option-1-use-local-system-volume-mounts-to-start-the-runner-container

Comment: Can you please paste your gitlab-runner configuration from the `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` file?

Comment: Can you also show the job YAML config? You may be missing some conifgs on job such as tag

Answer (score 0):

You need either set a runner "Tag" in your runner configuration AND in your job, or you need to set the runner configuration ["Run untagged jobs"](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#set-a-runner-to-run-untagged-jobs) and use no "tag" in your job.

In a job you would set a runner tag like this:

```
  job:
    tags:
      - myrunnertag
```